# Roslyn compiler in asp.net - conditional compilation symbols not picked up

Tags: asp.net, roslyn

With the previous version of the C# compiler one could define a compilation symbol the following way:

```
<configuration>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler
        language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        compilerOptions="/d:CUSTOMSYMBOL"
        type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, 
        System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
        PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

This however, doesn't seem to work with Roslyn compiler:

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" 
        compilerOptions="/d:CUSTOMSYMBOL"
            type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=0.2.0.0, Culture=neutral" warningLevel="4" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" compilerOptions="/optioninfer+" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0" />
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

Is this feature supported in the preview version of Roslyn compiler, and if so, what would be the proper way to configure it.

Comment: What sort of project is this?  Is it an asp.net vNext project, or a normal Web project?  If it's an asp.net vNext project, you need to set compilation options in the project.json file.

Comment: It is a normal Web project

Comment: I don't think this is related to the Roslyn compiler directly. It definitely does support conditional compilations, and for backwards compatibility they should be configured the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new version of Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform on nuget.org and it fixes this issue.